# inventory of app-only access

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I need to make an inventory of all App-Only access defined on site collection level, created according to this documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

I didn't find any option for this on the SharePoint admin center or any SPO powershell command. Can someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You could veiw the apps via this site

```
 https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/TA_AllAppPrincipals.aspx
```

In SharePoint admin center-> More features, clik Open Apps. In the Apps page, click App permissions.

Comment: Been there, I don't see the apps made on site level. With the search, I can find them by if I know the GUID, that, of course I don't know.

Comment: Navigate to the site collection, in site settings-> Site collection app permissions. Check if you can find the apps in that page. https://yoursitecollection/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx

Comment: I know how to do it for one site via the UI. But, as described, I need to make an inventory.  We have a few thousands site collections :)